# Как считать из потока текстовый файл ?

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Нужно считать текстовый файл из потока, как это сделано с картинкой.
**Важно:** считывание в ОП а не в файл.

```
ZipInputStream zis;
BufferedImage tmpImage;     
tmpImage = null;
tmpImage = ImageIO.read(zis);
```

Comment: Нихрена не понял, причем тут картинки и что такое ОП. Задача заключается в том, чтобы, имея произвольный поток InputStream, прочитать из него текст, чтобы получить на выходе строку (String)?

Comment: Это вроде бы он показал образец, а ему тоже самое только с текстовым файлом. ОП возможно оперативная память =)

Comment: вы правы =) ОП = оперативная память.  Да считать в String коли нет специального класса для текстовых файлов.  Желательно не вручную циклом

Comment: To @ckesc. Объясните толком. 

У Вас есть открытый поток, связанный с файлом, а имени этого файла Вы не знаете. И Вы хотите прочитать содержимое файла в String без циклов и возможного расширения (конечно создавая новый объект) String. 

Так что ли ?

Comment: @avp Нет. Грузится по сети zip архив. потоком ZipInutStream он распаковывается и из него можно уже доставать расжатые данные. Хочу на лету сохранить это, например, в String для последующего отображения пользователю. 
Важно не накосячить с переносами строк и кодировкой.
Сохранение во временный файл не желательно т.к. это апплет

Comment: В книжке Кея Хорстманна Java 2 (по моему во втором томе) был пример чтения данных из zip архива.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя только классы из стандартной библиотеки Java, избежать циклов и прочего говнокода не получится никак. Имея произвольный InputStream, прочитать из него текст в виде строки можно следующим образом:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.io.*;

static public String readTextFromInputStream(InputStream in, Charset cs) {
  StringBuilder text    = new StringBuilder();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, cs));
  String line = null;
  String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    text.append(line);
    text.append(newline);
  }
  return text.toString();
}
```

Где параметр cs означает предполагаемую кодировку текста. Использовать примерно так:

```
String text = readTextFromInputStream(in, Charset.forName("CP1251"));
```

Если хотите избежать всего этого говнокода, у вас два варианта: либо подключить внешние библиотеки (к примеру, [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/)), либо использовать нормальные языки для JVM, к примеру, [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), в которой решение займет одну строку:

```
def readFromInputStream(in: InputStream, cs: Codec) =
  Source.fromInputStream(in)(cs).mkString
```

**Дополнение 1**. Если хочется сохранить разбиение на строки, то модифицируем первоначальный вариант функции readFromInputStream следующим образом (так, чтобы она возвращала список строк):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

static public List<String> readLinesFromInputStream(InputStream in, Charset cs) {
  List<String> lines    = new ArrayList();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, cs));
  String line = null;
  String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(line + newline);
  }
  return lines;
}
```

Comment: Здорово!
Возможно ли автоматическое определение кодировки?
Есть ли класс чтобы сразу хранить разбиение на строки? Или же надо делать
* или массив строк
* или расставлять теги html (на сколько знаю jLabel поддерживает их)

Comment: Для этого придется использовать сторонние библиотеки. К примеру, juniversalchardet (http://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/) или jchardet (http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/). На stackoverflow.com видел отзыв, что вторая более точно определяет кодировки, по крайней мере латинские.

Comment: Дополнил ответ по вопросу о сохранении разбиения на строки.